# Jenkins Git ssh setup does not let me use username/password

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I am setting up my git plugin in Jenkins using my username/password to the git repo as my credential, however, it is still telling me the error "stderr: Permission denied (publickey). " I am not using ssh for this credential, why is it still telling me that?

[image: Error:]

Answer (score 0):

The user/password won't work with an ssh url

And the url you are using is not even an ssh one:

```
ssh://server/path
```

It should be:

```
ssh://user@server:path
      ^^^^       ^
      (login)
```

And you should not use a username/password anyway, but instead a public/private key, which you can specify though the [Jenkins Credentials SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin).

Comment: Do you have a guide on how to do this? I tried to config the ssh keys on my jenkins instance, and follow your advice, still does not work. I think it might have something to do with my known_host file not having the key in it. I am still not be able to connect.

Comment: @HarveyLin If it is a known_hosts issue, all you need to do is a `ssh user@server` on the Jenkins server, with the account running Jenkins: that will ask you to confirm the server, which will complete the `known_hosts`.