# jenkin git repository getting permission denied(publickey, password) for internal ssh server url

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I'm trying to configure flow which include git repository

things to note:

- i have a git server running in internal network
- my jenkin running on one of the machine in the network so it can access git server through local ip

normally i would go like this with my git command

```
git remote add origin ssh://username@git-server-ip/path-to-folder
```

after that it prompt me to type in the password for the above username

and i can work on the git repo like normal

The problems:

in Jenkin i already set up credential with "username and password" type

When i paste in the ssh url into the Repository URL, it take a while and return error:

> Failed to connect to repository ...
>
> stdout: stderr: Permission denied, please try again. Permission
> denied, please try again. username@git-server-ip: Permission denied
> (publickey, password). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

i had selected credentials and double check username and password it's correct. i tried running the ls-remote command manually in the terminal

```
git ls-remote -h -- ssh://username@git-server-ip/path-to-folder HEAD
```

it prompts to input the password, i typed it in and it run normal without error

Why is the error only happens on Jenkins when i input the repo ssh url? is username and password credential the wrong approach for credential? what else should i use?

there no guide online for Jenkin with internal git ssh url as i known of

the closest i can see my problem related to is this question [Jenkins Git ssh setup does not let me use username/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916501/jenkins-git-ssh-setup-does-not-let-me-use-username-password) , but it doesn't have an accepted answer yet, and the answer suggest going with "ssh username and private key"

Comment: Remember that Jenkins runs as the `jenkins` user, so you must give the `jenkins` user an appropriate ssh credential so that it can ssh into the server. When you use `git ls-remote` yourself, you're ssh-ing into the server as yourself. Note also that Git is not actually involved here, other than via the Jenkins-Git-ssh chain (that is, Git doesn't *take part* in the ssh-ing, it's just that instead of Jenkins invoking ssh directly, Jenkins invokes ssh by having Git do it).

Comment: @torek so what approach should i use? i see that credential have ssh username and private key option. Should i use that instead?

Comment: I'm not a "jenkins guy", every time I have to touch Jenkins at all I regret it. Find a Jenkins guy to advise you here.